# Converting a typescript library into a standalone javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, converters, deno

How can I convert a typescript library into a single javascript file?

For example, [oak](https://github.com/oakserver/oak) is a 3rd party library that provides itself via typescript. In [deno](https://deno.land/), you can import oak like this:

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
```

I would like to convert https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts to a standalone javascript file, that could be imported like this:

```
import { Application } from "./oak.js";
```

How can I accomplish this conversion?

Comment: create a ts file in vs and copy paste mod.ts on it and push build then js file will be generated .

Comment: @Mr.AF Is there a deno command that can accomplish this conversion? I don't use VS.

Comment: i am not familiar with deno but another approach is using this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ paste there.

Comment: Oh heck. I already asked basically the same question yesterday. It was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61883691/217867). So basically, you just do this deno command:  `deno bundle https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts oak.bundle.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [bundler](https://deno.land/manual/tools/bundler) tool with the `deno bundle` command:

```sh
deno bundle https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts oak.js
```

You can now import `oak.js` and use it on your JavaScript code:

```js
import { Application } from "./oak.js";

const app = new Application();

app.use((ctx) => {
  ctx.response.body = "Hello World!";
});

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```